# CustomLinkedList with generics

Tags: java, generics

I implementing a linkedlist with generics. But I'm getting "Multiple markers at this line
    - The type MyIterator is not generic; it cannot be parameterized 
     with arguments 
"
at the return statement.
Figure is an interface

```
public Iterator<Figure> iterator() {

    class MyIterator implements Iterator<Figure> {
        private Node current;

        private MyIterator(Node n) {
            current = n;
        }

        public boolean hasNext() {
            return current.next != null;
        }

        public Figure next() throws NoSuchElementException {
            if (current.next == null)
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            current.setNext(current.next);
            Object c=current;
            return (Figure) c;
        }

        public void remove() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

    }

    return new MyIterator<Figure>();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly `MyIterator` is not generic. You've use it like generic type. Change your return statement to:

```
return new MyIterator();
```